# How to cutting a video and keep all format and metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I want to cut long videos into several smaller parts without changing any format and metadata from the original video.

[image: Original]

I used these commands

> ffmpeg -i input -ss 00:00:05 -t 100 -c:a copy -c:v copy output
>
> ffmpeg -i input -ss 00:00:05 -t 100 -metadata "major_brand=mp42, minor_version=0" -c:v copy -c:a copy output
>
> ffmpeg -i input -ss 00:00:05 -t 100 -map_metadata 0 -c:v copy -c:a  copy output
>
> ffmpeg -i input -ss 00:00:05 -t 100 -map_metadata 0 -b:v 460k -c:a  copy output

[image: Result]

but still get different results from the original video.

Is there another command that I can use for cutting the video with metadata results identical to the original one ?

Thanks

Comment: Which metadata do you wish to preserve?

Comment: @Mulvya i want to keep Major Brand and minor brand, is that possible? and could you tell me what the meaning of handler_name :IsoMedia File Produce by Google. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg only allows you to alter/override the major brand, not the minor.

Command is

```
ffmpeg -i input -ss 00:00:05 -t 100 -brand mp42 -c:v copy -c:a copy output
```

[MP4box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) will allow you to override both.

```
mp4box -brand mp42:0 file.mp4
```

If you want to change the handler name as well, use

```
mp4box -brand mp42:0 -name 2="IsoMedia File Produce by Google" file.mp4
```

(2 is the track index i.e. the 2nd track)